# Group by one column and find first of two columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have one dataframe geomerge, I need to group by one column `grpno.` and select first of column `MaxOfcount percent` and first of column `state code` and display `grpno.` also. I have rename them as `FirstOfMaxOfState count percent` and `FirstOfstate code`

My input dataframe:

```
      count percent  grpno. state code  MaxOfcount percent
0          14.78       1         CA               14.78
1           0.00       2         CA                0.00
2           0.00       2         FL                0.00
3           8.80       3         CA                8.80
4           0.00       6         NC                0.00
5           0.00       5         NC                0.00
6          59.00       4         MA               59.00
```

My output dataframe:

```
      FirstOfMaxOfState count percent  state pool number FirstOfstate code
0                            14.78                  1                CA
1                             0.00                  2                CA
2                             8.80                  3                CA
3                            59.00                  4                MA
4                             0.00                  5                NC
5                             0.00                  6                NC
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the unneeded column, group by `grpno`, take the first value, and flatten the multi-index:

```
df2 = df.drop('count percent', 1).groupby('grpno.').take([0]).reset_index(0)
```

Rename the columns:

```
mapping = {'state code':'FirstOfstate code' ,
           'grpno.': 'state pool number',
           'MaxOfcount percent': 'FirstOfMaxOfState count percent'}
df2.rename_axis(mapping, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> df2

   state pool number  FirstOfMaxOfState count percent FirstOfstate code
0                  1                            14.78                CA
1                  2                             0.00                CA
3                  3                             8.80                CA
6                  4                            59.00                MA
5                  5                             0.00                NC
4                  6                             0.00                NC
```